# Compare arrays and search for matching values

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, `$arr1` and `$arr2`:

`$arr1` is a list of columns that I expect to read from an excel file, `$arr2` is the array of columns that were actually found.

Sometimes the uploaded file contains

- Misspelled column names
- Columns in a different order
- Could be missing some columns
- Also, the column names might contain letters in a different charset (ex. a greek 'M' that looks like a latin *M* but cannot be accounted as the same).

Lets say, for example, that we have the following 2 arrays:

```
$arr1 = array('Action', 'LotSize', 'QuantityMinimum', 'SupplierName', 'SPN',
 'PartNumExt', 'UOM', 'ListPrice', 'MPN', 'MFrName', 'CatLevel1', 'CatLevel2',
 'CatLevel3', 'CatLevel4', 'CatLevel5', 'CatLevel6', 'AcctLevel1', 'AcctLevel2', 
 'AcctLevel3', 'AcctLevel4', 'AcctLevel5', 'AcctLevel6', 'Desc1', 'Desc2', 'PicName',
 'SupplierURL', 'CatPart','TechSpec', 'Kad');    

$arr2 = array('Action', 'LotSze', 'QuantityMinimum', 'SupplierName', 'SPN',
 'PartNumEx', 'UOM', 'ListPric', 'MPN', 'MfrName', 'CatLevel1', 'CatLevel2',
 'CatLevel3', 'CatLevel4', 'AcctLevel1', 'AcctLevel2', 'AcctLevel3', 'AcctLevel4',
 'Desc1', 'Desc2', 'PicName', 'SupplierURL', 'CatPart');
```

I need to compare the 2 arrays and save the position of the matching elements to a 3rd array:

```
$arr3 = ([0]=>0, [1]=>1, [2]=>3, [3]=>5, [4]=>6, [5]=>...);
```

displaying the position of each matched element of `$arr1` in `$arr2`.

By 'matching' I mean all elements that are identical (ex. **Action**), or partially the same (ex. **Test** & **Tes**, ) and also those elements that are alike but are in different case (ex. **Foo** & **foo**, **Bar** & **bar**).

I posted [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153695/) a few days ago and I got a good answer but after several tests with more sample data I've found that it doesn't always work as expected.

So after more searching I found the [**levenshtein**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) function so I did a combination that first checks for an exact match and if not found, then tries to find the closest match. Now, the problem is that some columns have similar names, ex. **Catlevel1**, **Catlevel2**,...,**Catlevel6**. So if **Catlevel2** is missing, it will be matched with the last & most similar column which is **Catlevel6**.

This is what I have so far:

```
foreach($all_columns as $i => $val1) {
    $result = null;
    // Search the second array for an exact match, if found
    if(($found = array_search($val1,$_SESSION['found_columns'],true)) !==false) {
        $result = $found; 
    } else {
        // Otherwise, see if we can find a case-insensitive matching string 
        //where the element from $arr2 is found within the one from $arr1
        foreach( $_SESSION['found_columns'] as $j => $val2) {
            if($val1<>'' && $val2<>'') {
                if( stripos( $val1, $val2) !== false ) {
                    $result = $j;
                    break;
                } else {
                    $notfound .= $val1.', ';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['found_column_positions'][$i] = $result;
}

/*****ALTERNATIVE METHOD USING levenshtein*****/
$i=0;
foreach($all_columns as $key => $value) {
    $found = wordMatch($value, $arr2, 2);
    $pos = array_search($found, $_SESSION['found_columns']); 
    $_SESSION['found_column_positions'][$i] = $pos;
    $i++;
}
```

---

```
function wordMatch($input, $array, $sensitivity){
    $words = $array;
    $shortest = -1;
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $lev = levenshtein($input, $word);
        if ($lev == 0) {
            $closest = $word;
            $shortest = 0;
            break;
        }
        if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
            $closest  = $word;
            $shortest = $lev;
        }
    }
    if($shortest <= $sensitivity){
        return $closest;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

Is there a better way to compare 2 arrays, find the closest value matches and save the matching value key to 3rd array to use as a key reference between the 2 arrays?

Comment: http://in3.php.net/array_diff **&** http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

Comment: Does this need to be fully automated?  Because my thought would be to create a small 'wizard' that would let the user specify which column is which, then just save the user-input mapping.

Comment: You're doing fuzzy matching, so you're going to get false positives; that is the whole point of fuzzy matching, really. Unless you can come up with hard-and-fast rules like "don't accept matches where the only differences are in numeric last characters", you're going to have to manually pick through the iffy ones. Ask yourself this, though: do you really want to try to account for every way that a person can screw up a column name?

Comment: @Wolfman Joe: Yes, it needs to be automated. It will be part of an application for importing an accountable number of files daily.

Comment: I agree with the previous 2 comments. You can write a script to automatize a process, but there are limits within you dont wanna play. Set some rules, for example with the catlevel problem even a human would have difficulties to see in which field it would have to fit.

You need to find the balance between the data source correctness and your automatization.

If you are getting those files through different sources don't take all the responsability and be strict, or in a few weeks you will be patching your script up with hundreds of exceptions.

Comment: @WolfmanJoe that's the right thing to do. KISS!

Comment: @bikey77 if `$arr1 = array('Desc1', 'Desc2')` and `$arr2 = array('Desc')`. This is going to be error prone.

Comment: If these files are being generated automatically, then why are the columns going to vary and be misnamed?  Perhaps you're focusing your efforts at the wrong location?  Go to the automated processes generating these files and make sure their column names are correct.

Comment: The files are not auto generated, they are created and loaded by the users.

Comment: @bikey77 Then it's not fully automated.  You *can* have a small wizard that would let the user specify which column is which, then save the user-input mapping.

Comment: or just don't import the file if there's a column mismatch. Users will learn to be careful and spell right eventually

Comment: Are you also trying to account for bad numbers? e.g. cat1 shoudld be cat2, or al1 (#1) should be all, etc.?

Comment: Although columns might not be spelled correctly, we need to try to identify them and process the data in each. When errors are found in either header or data the file is sent back to the client for revision and corrections. If only minor mistakes are found it is processed normally.

Comment: Then run your comparison on the file right away, get your best guess.  If it's exactly right, then bypass the mapping stage.  If it's not right, but you have a 'best guess', then let those 'best guesses' be the default selection for dropdowns for valid column titles.  This will save you a lot of turnaround time by putting all the error-checking and user-feedback stuff out of the way right at the beginning.

Comment: You could also use the way mentioned by Wolfman Joe to build up a set of common lapsis and check against these lapsis as well, thus reducing the manual effort gradually. Also you might want to consider using temporary tables for the comparisons, thus leveraging the advatages for comparison in, say MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Following script will do the work.

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('Action', 'LotSize', 'QuantityMinimum', 'SupplierName', 'SPN',
 'PartNumExt', 'UOM', 'ListPrice', 'MPN', 'MFrName', 'CatLevel1', 'CatLevel2',
 'CatLevel3', 'CatLevel4', 'CatLevel5', 'CatLevel6', 'AcctLevel1', 'AcctLevel2', 
 'AcctLevel3', 'AcctLevel4', 'AcctLevel5', 'AcctLevel6', 'Desc1', 'Desc2', 'PicName',
 'SupplierURL', 'CatPart','TechSpec', 'Kad');    

$arr2 = array('Action', 'LotSze', 'QuantityMinimum', 'SupplierName', 'SPN',
 'PartNumEx', 'UOM', 'ListPric', 'MPN', 'MfrName', 'CatLevel1', 'CatLevel2',
 'CatLevel3', 'CatLevel4', 'AcctLevel1', 'AcctLevel2', 'AcctLevel3', 'AcctLevel4',
 'Desc1', 'Desc2', 'PicName', 'SupplierURL', 'CatPart');

$arr3 = array();

foreach($arr1 as $key=>$val)
{
    $arr3[$key] = array_search($val, $arr2);
}

print_r($arr3);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is an option for you or not, but we have a similar system where the users manage a page to tell us what are the possible values for each header.  Then the system converts to the standard accepted header before attempting to upload. based off the mapping created by the users.  This avoids forcing the user to map each time.  If there is no entry for one of the columns they are attempting to upload, the upload throws an error.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('Action', 'LotSize', 'QuantityMinimum', 'SupplierName', 'SPN',
'PartNumExt', 'UOM', 'ListPrice', 'MPN', 'MFrName', 'CatLevel1', 'CatLevel2',
'CatLevel3', 'CatLevel4', 'CatLevel5', 'CatLevel6', 'AcctLevel1', 'AcctLevel2', 
'AcctLevel3', 'AcctLevel4', 'AcctLevel5', 'AcctLevel6', 'Desc1', 'Desc2', 'PicName',
'SupplierURL', 'CatPart','TechSpec', 'Kad');  

$arr2 = array('Action', 'LotSze', 'QuantityMinimum', 'SupplierName', 'SPN',
'PartNumEx', 'UOM', 'ListPric', 'MPN', 'MfrName', 'CatLevel1', 'CatLevel2',
'CatLevel3', 'CatLevel4', 'AcctLevel1', 'AcctLevel2', 'AcctLevel3', 'AcctLevel4',
'Desc1', 'Desc2', 'PicName', 'SupplierURL', 'CatPart');

$arr3=array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr1) ;$i++)
{ 
$max=0;
$result=0;
for ($j=0; $j< count($arr2) ; $j++)
{
     $percent=find($arr1[$i],$arr2[$j]);
     if ($percent>$max) 
             { $max= $percent;
               $result=$j; 
            } 

 }
 $arr3[$i]=$result;
}
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr3) ;$i++)
    echo "[".$i."]=> ".$arr3[$i].", ";

function find($a,$b)
{
similar_text($a, $b, $percent);
return $percent;
}
?>
```

This is the full program. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
?php
$arr1 = array('Action', 'LotSize', 'QuantityMinimum', 'SupplierName', 'SPN',
'PartNumExt', 'UOM', 'ListPrice', 'MPN', 'MFrName', 'CatLevel1', 'CatLevel2',
'CatLevel3', 'CatLevel4', 'CatLevel5', 'CatLevel6', 'AcctLevel1', 'AcctLevel2', 
'AcctLevel3', 'AcctLevel4', 'AcctLevel5', 'AcctLevel6', 'Desc1', 'Desc2', 'PicName',
'SupplierURL', 'CatPart','TechSpec', 'Kad');  

$arr2 = array('Action', 'LotSze', 'QuantityMinimum', 'SupplierName', 'SPN',
'PartNumEx', 'UOM', 'ListPric', 'MPN', 'MfrName', 'CatLevel1', 'CatLevel2',
'CatLevel3', 'CatLevel4', 'AcctLevel1', 'AcctLevel2', 'AcctLevel3', 'AcctLevel4',
'Desc1', 'Desc2', 'PicName', 'SupplierURL', 'CatPart');

$arr3 = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2));
echo arr3 ;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple algorithm is this, using [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-search.php):

```
$mapping = [];

foreach ($arr1 as $i => $value)
{
    $actualKey = array_search($value, $arr2);

    if (false !== $actualKey)
    {
        $mapping[$i] = $actualKey;
    }
}
```

#### array_search($needle, $haystack)

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful [false otherwise]

Answer (score 0):

Use inner and outer loop concept for this.

```
<pre>
$arr1 = $ar1;
$arr2 = $ar2;
$matching_vals = '';
foreach($arr1 as $array1){
$val_arr1 = $array1;
foreach($arr2 as $array2){
$val_arr2 = $array1;
if($val_arr2 == $val_arr1){
$matching_vals .= $val_arr2;
}
}
}
```

echo 'Match values are: '.  $matching_vals;

Concept is to take one array and iterate it in a loop and compare with each value of second array. This is algo to do this.